# How can a skill be upgraded past level 20?

Tags: mission-of-crisis

On Mission of Crisis on the Android, how do I get past Level 20 for talents or skills? Further talents and skills require the previous one to be at least level 21 or higher, but the Upgrade button disappears once it hits 20. I should also mention that the skills previous to the capped skill is also up to 20, with the Upgrade button now gone.

**Update**: Every weapon and skill that I can is upgraded to Level 20. It seems like no matter what I do, I cannot move past this barrier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When emailing their support team about this bug, this is what I received:

> Dear Sir,
>   Yes, the highest level to be 20.
>   But we will release for MOC 2 SOON.
>   Please looking forward to it.

So I assume that this won't get fixed... goodteam@gts8.com was their support address.